# What novel series has a young boy travelling across space with librarians and a bat-like dog?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to dig up the name of a novel-series I read when I was a child (early 90's) but I simply cannot recall either the name of the writer nor the name of any of the books.

The series has a young boy in the center who is accepted into a conclave of Librarians who travel the universe in a massive spaceship. The members of the conclave value knowledge above all else and during the books they visit different worlds where each world presents a new challenge in regards to corrupt governments, dormant threats and so on. The Librarians "battle" these problems using their vast knowledge and skills.

The boy is followed by a sort of bat-like dog throughout the series and the animal is present on all the book-covers in the series.

I recall one book taking place in a vast sea-dominated world and another on a wood covered planet... but apart form that I am at a loss.

Comment: I don't know the series, but it sounds intriguing. Was it aimed at children, YA or adults?

Comment: It was mainly aimed at teens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book series was written by the recently deceased Norwegian author [Jon Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Bing) in the seventies and eighties, and published collectively under the name *[The Chronicles of the Starship Alexandria](https://www.goodreads.com/series/82046-kr-niken-om-stjerneskipet-alexandria)* in 1997, so if you read them in the early nineties the series itself probably didn't have an official name; it consists of four novels in which the library starship Alexandria visits four different planets:

- *Azur - Planet of the Captains* (the sea-dominated world, where a benevolent totalitarian government of ecological activists has banned most technology)
- *Zalt - Planet of the Steamlords* (a desert world where the feudal leaders control all drinking water)
- *Mizt - Planet of the Ghosts* (a technocracy works to solve a scientific problem; probably the wood covered planet, as it features "hunters" and "werewolves" who kill people who escape from the forced scientific labour)
- *Tanz - Planet of Riddles* (humanity's first encounter with an alien being on an artificial planet)

The boy is the orphan Benji from the first planet, and the name of his "bat cat" is Miromurr.

Comment: YES! You Sir, just saved my day.

Thank you very, very much.