# A scifi young-adult series from late 90s or early 2000s, called "Odyssey?"

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Looking for this English language series I read sometime around 2005. There must have been five or six books in this series. It involved a group of friends, some kind of spaceship, and possibly aliens. I believe the title of the series or one of the books in the series was "Odyssey," or a similar sounding word, but I haven't been able to find anything. Does this ring any bells for anybody? Thanks!

My vague memory is that this was a sort of adventure/coming of age series. Not very comedic. Something like a bunch of regular young adults getting swept up in a grand scheme due to a cataclysmic or paradigm-shifting event.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like a YA series by Norwegian author Jon Bing about the voyages of the starship Alexandria, and I guess it might be possible to mix up Odyssey and Alexandria, both being ancient Mediterranean. However, I am not sure if the books were ever translated into English, even thoough Wikipedia has English titles for the books. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Bing

Comment: If so it would be a duplicate of [What novel series has a young boy travelling across space with librarians and a bat-like dog?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50969/what-novel-series-has-a-young-boy-travelling-across-space-with-librarians-and-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long shot, but could it be the [Outernet series by Steve Barlow](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76526-outernet).

> A wild ride through strange galaxies and unexpected adventures. But watch your step -- and don't step in anything gross or smelly along the way!
>
> The Outernet is a web of intergalactic computer networks linked through Servers on different planets. As the series opens, we discover that the evil Tyrant and his henchmen (the FOES) are trying to take over the Outernet and use its powers to control the galaxy.
> Our heroes, including several not-so-lucky Earth kids, accidentally connect to the Outernet via a lost Server. They must work with the Friends of the Outernet to keep freedom and liberty in the Galaxy. They are assisted (and often hindered) by a hilarious dog and cat team who are disguised agents of the Friends and the FOES.

The first book was published in 2002, so the date matches, there are six books in the series, and [the third book of the series is indeed called Odyssey](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1306033.Odyssey).

> We are not alone. We might wish that we were... But we're definitely not. As Jack, Merle, and Loaf have discovered, there is life on other planets -- and lots of it. In fact, they're planet-hopping as they try to keep the Server safe from the FOEs. And they keep meeting all sorts of ALFs (Alien Life Forces), including creepy spider things on Planet Arachnus. The kids' mission? To find the "genius" who created the Outernet. But with the bad guys hot on their cosmic trail, the mission gets sidetracked. And now they're journeying to different galaxies. Galaxies far, far a -- well... you get the drift.

Comment: This is it! Thanks, don't think I would have found that otherwise.